# How to Log HTTP requests and responses inside OnActionExecutionAsync ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

How can I Log HTTP requests and responses inside OnActionExecutionAsync?

Comment: I would recommend starting with an article like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and posting your attempt here for help rather than just asking a question. You can also look into a logging library like serilog that already has this built in for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[OnActionExecutionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecutionasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is called before the action method is invoked. You can actually access the HttpContext and get the HttpRequest Headers and Body if that's what you want. However the response cannot be accessed here because it is not yet computed.

```
public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var headers = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
        var body = context.HttpContext.Request.Body;

        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
```

If what you are trying to achieve is, just log your API requests and responses, I would recommend instead to use a logging [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0). There are tons of examples on google like [this](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/) one.